# English translation of Tur Yoreh Deah

Tags: product-recommendation, translation, yoreh-deah, tur

I am looking for a translation of the Tur's Yoreh Deah, specifically [siman 335](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6479). I have not been able to find a translation online anywhere. [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tur%2C_Yoreh_Deah.335?lang=bi) has some of it, but not that siman. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one:

הלכות ביקור חולים ורפואה ונוטה למות

Laws of visiting the sick, medicine and the deathbed

קוצר דברים לספר תורת האדם שחבר הרב הגדול הרמב"ן עם קצת דעות אחרות שאכניס בו ועל כל דבר ודבר אכתוב מסקנת א"א הרא"ש ז"ל ועל הסדר שסידר הרב חוץ מהדברים שכתבתי במקומות אחרים

This is a compendium of the work of the great rabbi Ramban, in his book Torath Haadam. Combined with other opinions I will record the conclusions of my father the Rosh of blessed memory. According to the rabbi’s order, I have order my present writings here, save for several items.

א"ר יצחק בריה דרב יהודה לעולם יבקש אדם שלא יחלה שאם חלה אומרים לו הבא זכות ותפטר וכיון שחלה האדם מצוה על כל אדם לבקרו שכן מצינו בהקב"ה שמבקר חולים

Rav Yitzchak son of Rav Yehuda says: One should request of God that his friend shall not fall ill, for if he does fall ill, his merits will become used up in order to remove the illness. Once a person becomes sick it is a mitzvah on every individual to go and visit the sick. This is what is found by God Himself.

כמו שדרשו בפסוק וירא אליו ה' באלוני ממרא מלמד שבא אליו לבקר החולה וסמכוה אקרא והודעת להם את הדרך ילכו בה ומצוה גדולה היא לבקר שמתוך כך יבקש עליו רחמים ונמצא כאילו מחיה אותו וגם מתוך שרואהו מעיין בענינו אם יצטרך לשום דבר משתדל בו 
להמציאו לו ועושה שיכבדו וירבצו לפניו

In the verse “And God appeared to him in the plains of Mamre” the rabbis taught that this means that God came to visit the sick [Abraham], and the rabbis based this on the verse “And you shall inform them of the path which they shall go on”. Furthermore, it is indeed a great mitzvah to visit the sick, since through the process he will beseech God for mercy on the ill, and it is as if he resurrected him into life. By seeing the patient alone he will be able to see if he needs anything to be taken care of, including cleaning and washing.

והקרובים נכנסין מיד לבקרו והרחוקים אחר ג' ימים והחברים כקרובים ואם קפץ עליו החולי אלו ואלו נכנסין מיד ואפי' הגדול ילך לבקר הקטן ואפילו כמה פעמים ביום ואפי' בן גילו שנוטל א' מס' בחליו וכל המוסיף הרי זה משובח ובלבד שלא יטריח לו ולא ישב ע"ג מטה ולא ע"ג כסא ולא על ספסל אלא מתעטף ויושב לפניו שהשכינה למעלה מראשותיו של חולה שנאמר ה' יסעדנו על ערש דוי

Close relatives visit right away, other acquaintances may visit after three days have passed. Friends have the same status as close relatives. However, if one gets sick very suddenly everyone may visit right away. A great person visits even the most insignificant of individuals, even several times per day. Even one who has certain similarities  to the patient, so much that he removes one sixtieth of the patients illness in a visit. It is indeed a praiseworthy endeavor for anyone who increases in visiting; the more the merrier! As long as one does not cause strain on the patient; likewise one should not sit on the patients bed, chair or couch. Rather one should sit at an appropriate distant, since there is a divine presence above the patients head, as the verse says “God assists him when sick in bed”.

ואין מבקרין אותו בג' שעות ראשונות של יום מפני שכל חולה מיקל עליו חוליו בבקר ולא יחוש לבקש עליו רחמים וכן לא בג' שעות אחרונות של יום שאז מכביד עליו חוליו ויתיאש מלבקש עליו רחמים

One may not visit the patient in the first three hours of the day, since every patient’s illness is lightened during that period of the day, the visitor will not think to pray for the patient while there. Similarly, one should not visit during the last three hours of the day, since during that period his illness increases in strength, and the visitor will give up hope and not pray for him.

וכשמבקש עליו רחמים אם מבקש לפניו יכול לבקש בין בכל לשון בין בלשון הקדש ושלא בפניו לא יבקש אלא בלשון הקודש כשאר תפלות יחיד

When praying for the sick, one may pray in any language, provided that he is in front of the patient. However, one not in front of the patient, one may only pray in Hebrew, like other private prayers.

ויכלול אותו עם חולי ישראל שיאמר המקום ירחם עליך בתוך חולי ישראל ובשבת יאמר שבת היא מלזעוק ורפואה קרובה לבא ורחמיו מרובין ושבתו בשלום

One should include this patients with the rest of those in the nation of Yisroel. One should say “May God have mercy on you, among those sick in Yisroel”. On Sabbath one says “It is Sabbath, don’t cry! Healing is coming soon, God’s mercy is abundant and His Sabbath is with peace”.

ומזכירין אותו שיתן דעתו על עניניו דתניא משעלה אדם למטה נכנסין אצלו ואומרים לו לא דברים מחיים ולא דברים ממיתים שמא הלוית או שמא הלוך אדם או שמא הפקדת אצל בני אדם או הפקידו אצלך פי' אומרים לו שיתן דעתו על עניניו ואל יפחד מפני זה יותר מן המות. 
[...]

אין מבקרים לא לחולי מעיים ולא לחולי העין ולא לחולי הראש חולי המעיים משום כיסופא חולי העין והראש מפני שהדבור קשה ליה הלכך כל חולי דתקיף ליה עלמא וקשה ליה דבורא אין מבקרין אותו בפניו אלא נכנסין בבית החיצון ושואלין ודורשים בו אם צריכים לכבד ולרבץ לפניו וכיוצא בו ושומעין צערו ומבקשין עליו רחמים.

One does not visit someone with a stomach illness, eye illness or head illness. The stomach illness is on account of the am embarrassment associated with it. The eye and head illnesses are because it is difficult during that time is especially painful to hear speech. Thus, any patient who finds speech difficult may not be visited directly. Rather, one must enter the outer area and inquire of the patient’s needs, may they be washing or cleaning, and one asks about the illness and prays for him.

מבקרין חולי נכרים מפני דרכי שלום תניא האיש משמש האיש בחולי המעיים אבל לא את האשה והאשה משמשת האשה והאיש בחולי המעיים ראובן שאסר הנאתו על שמעון וחלה שמעון יכול ליכנס לו ולבקרו

Non-Jewish patients are visited in order to keep the peace and not differentiate. It is taught: The man tends to a man with stomach illness but not a woman. Likewise, a woman tends to a woman or a man with stomach illness. 
Reuven who prohibited Shimon to benefit from him, and then Shimon falls ill, Reuven may visit him.

ובמקום שנותנין שכר למי שישב אצל החולה לצוות לו לא ישב אצלו אלא מבקרו מעומד ואם חלה בנו של שמעון יכול ראובן ליכנס לו ולישב עמו ולבקרו אם נכסי שמעון אסורין על ראובן וחלה שמעון נכנס ראובן לבקרו מעומד אבל לא ישב חלה בנו אינו נכנס כלל אלא שואל עליו בשוק:

A location in which those who sick by the sick or compensated, one should not sit by the patient, rather one should stay standing and visit in that way. If the son of Shimon falls ill, Rueven can sit with him to visit. If the property of Shimon are forbidden to Reuven, and Shimon falls ill, Reuven may visit him standing, but may not sit. If his son falls sick, he may not enter at all, rather he inquires of him in the marketplace.